# Accessing a text box inside a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I'm having problems binding a user control. I have a main window, which with a press of a button gets my value. However when i use my user control in the main window i cant set the text box to add my value. Instead of 'text' i want my user control text box? I have tried to declaring the text box but no luck any ideas?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    text.Clear();
    text.AppendText( tc.FTemp + "F");   
} 

<my:UserControl1 Height="172" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,197,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151" Loaded="userControl11_Loaded" />
```

Comment: Create a property in the usercontrol, so you can access the control in the main window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Create a public property in your user control
2. Use 'Controls.Find' (the slowest, but easiest way)

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       Control[] control = userControl1.Controls.Find("textbox1", true);
       control.First().Text = "Found!";
   }
   ```